# Tizen Emulator - Push File to emulator

Tags: c#, tizen, tizen-emulator

I'm looking for a way to upload files to the TV emulator, or some way to the emulator to be able to see media files on the pc. So far i've tried:

1. Shared directory
2. Device manager (which does not allow to list/push files to the emulator, it is like somehow it is not connected)
   [Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql651.png)
3. drag the file direct to the emulator window (which in case, it does copy, but the app doesnt list the files)

PS: i'm running the TV sample https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen-CSharp-Samples/tree/master/TV/MusicPlayer

Using Tizen Studio 3.3, VS2017 and Xamarin forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of Tizen TV emulator, 
Unable to push files using sdb.
Needs to embed files or downloads it via network.

Comment: What do you mean? Embedded the file inside the .tpk? And how do i download it? (or you meant doing it by code?)

Comment: In case of TV Profile, by the security reason, Pushing files is not allowed for 3rd party developer. If you can get 2nd party privilege, you can do it.

Comment: To embed media files in res folder, refer to C# TV sample apps. https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen-CSharp-Samples => TV => MediaHubSample or Gallery

Comment: Oki, i'll follow your advice and check the sample. But too bad we can not add media directly to the emulator (not even through shared folder)

Comment: TV was limited by security policy. If you want to push files to emulator, you can use mobile emulator.